# Установить ограничения в storyboard для картинки

Tags: ios, xcode

Доброй ночи, возник один вопрос, никогда не любил подгонять картинки дизайнеров под разные разрешения экрана. У меня есть изображение в png (@1x, @2x, @3x), я добавляю его на экран (подгоняю под iphone 5s). Выставляю ограничения по краям и по ширине с высотой. Когда тестирую на 5s, то все отлично, а когда на 6 или 6 plus, то оно значительно уменьшается. Подскажите как установить ограничения или может быть что-то другое нужно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. Не обращайте внимание на стрелку спидометра, еще не дошли руки для ее установки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:
Фиксированное расстояние до лево-право-верх и фиксированный aspect ratio если constraints;

[image: список констрейнтов]

или если autoresizing mask то флексибл все, кроме bottom:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень выручили!